# Display MySQL query results with variable data in an HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a query to get the values I need:

```
SELECT `UserId` FROM `usertable` WHERE `AssignedUserId` = '$userid';
```

The maximum number of results for the query will constantly 8.

However, depending on when the query was run, the results may vary. Minimum will always be 1.

I display the results in an HTML table and if the value is 8, it displays:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| value 1  | value 2  | value 3  | value 4  |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| vaule 5  | value 6  | value 7  | value 8  |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

If the values are less, let's say 5, it should display this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| value 1  | value 2  | value 3  | value 4  |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| vaule 5  |  empty   |  empty   |  empty   |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Right now, I'm using this PHP code for the values:

```
if (GetRows > 0) {
  $temp2 = FetchArray;

  $tmpu0 = $temp2[0];      
  $tmpu1 = $temp2[1];
  $tmpu2 = $temp2[2];
  $tmpu3 = $temp2[3];
  $tmpu4 = $temp2[4];
  $tmpu5 = $temp2[5];
  $tmpu6 = $temp2[6];
  $tmpu7 = $temp2[7];
} else {
  $tmpu0 = "Empty";
  $tmpu1 = "Empty";
  $tmpu2 = "Empty";
  $tmpu3 = "Empty";
  $tmpu4 = "Empty";
  $tmpu5 = "Empty";
  $tmpu6 = "Empty";
  $tmpu7 = "Empty";
}
```

However, it only displays correctly when the value is 8. Otherwise I get a blank table. Not even "Empty".

What am I not doing correctly? Is there a better way of getting the results I want?

Your help is appreciated...

Thank you!

Full PHP File:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `UserId` FROM `usertable` WHERE `AssignedUserId` = '$userid'";

$results = Query($sql);

if (Rows($results) > 0) {
  $temp2 = Fetch($results);

  $tmpu0 = $temp2[0];
  $tmpu1 = $temp2[1];
  $tmpu2 = $temp2[2];
  $tmpu3 = $temp2[3];
  $tmpu4 = $temp2[4];
  $tmpu5 = $temp2[5];
  $tmpu6 = $temp2[6];
  $tmpu7 = $temp2[7];
} else {
  $tmpu0 = "Empty";
  $tmpu1 = "Empty";
  $tmpu2 = "Empty";
  $tmpu3 = "Empty";
  $tmpu4 = "Empty";
  $tmpu5 = "Empty";
  $tmpu6 = "Empty";
  $tmpu7 = "Empty";
}
?>

<table border="1" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Users</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu0; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu1; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu2; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu3; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu4; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu5; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu6; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $tmpu7; ?></td>
    </tr>          
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code. It looks like you are well off base on this one from what you have shown so far.

Comment: Right, post full relevant code please, I'm now not sure if I fully adressed your issue in my answer.

Comment: Added full PHP code block...

Comment: Replaced PHP code block with the whole PHP file.

Comment: Jon its fairly basic, you select a single column from a table, to process the result of that query you are using functions we cannot see! But basically it looks like you think you will get multiple results (columns) from a query that will only return one column

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks! I took a step back and figured there was something wrong with one of the functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make array with all values 'Empty' and then replays it with values, comming from DB

```
$temp2 = array_replace(array_fill(0, 8, "Empty"), FetchArray);
```

Comment: did you write `<?php echo $temp2[0]; ?>`? and i lost `$` before $temp2 :(

Comment: I had a bad function. Your solution works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
$values = [];
for (var $i=0; $i<8;$i++) {
  $values[$i] = !empty($temp2[$i]) ? $temp2[$i] : 'Empty';
}
```

Then `$values` will always have 8 elements in it and when there is no value from DB (?) then empty string will be set in place.

Comment: I get an error-> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @JonDavis then update your PHP, short array syntax `[]` was introduced in 5.4.0